# Quanvolutional NN vs Quantum Convolution NN

Tags: machine-learning, quantum-enhanced-machine-learning

There are 2 primary approaches for Image recognition using Quantum Neural Networks: 1. Quanvolutional one and 2. Quantum Convolutional Neural Networks. The primary difference is that in 1 we don't train the network and in 2 we do. In 1 we use the idea of using Random Filters and try to sort of magnify different features of the images which would lead to a more trainable dataset and in 2 we train the said filters like we normally do with Convolutional layers.

So the primary thing in two cases is that in the first one, we simply choose a random point(let's say A) and in the second one we start with A and we define a measure of accuracy for the model, using said measure of accuracy and A as starting point we move towards a better point. So isn't approach 2 always bound to overcome approach 1?